# Nativescript app build and comments

Tags: build, compilation, comments, nativescript

What happens to all the comments in my code when I build my nativescript application. Are those included making application performance little slower or does nativescript build automatically delete all comments. I'm using javascript if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are ignored.  The amount of time to parse it with or without comments is normal so minuscule you can't even notice it.

However, if you really are looking for every particle of a nano second in speed; you can minimize the js which would eliminate comments and shrink the code which does allow the parser to be a tad faster...